# Getting MIME type not supported

Tags: javascript, css, node.js, express

I am having a very strange issue, however, i have resolved it but wanted to know why. I am using node.js with express.
In my server.js file i have written route code like:

```
app.get('/eventname/:event', (req, res) => {
res.render('event.hbs', {
    name: req.user.displayName
});
})
```

There is no specific "eventname" route when i tried to load pages, it loads successfully just it doesn't loads my .css files giving **MIME type not supported** error. However, when i removes the "eventname"

```
app.get('/:event', (req, res) => {
res.render('event.hbs', {
    name: req.user.displayName
});
})
```

Everything started wroking fine. 
Why is this happening, am i doing something wrong in express?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not 100% certain, but I'm pretty sure that this happens because the `<link>` tag you use to import the CSS file uses a relative path.

---

Let's imagine it looks like this ...

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
```

... and the URL of the event page you're visiting is `https://example.com/example-event`. In that case the relative path used for the CSS will resolve to the absolute path `https://example.com/styles.css` which is – I assume – the **correct path**.

Now imagine that you're instead using the first code example and the URL is `https://example.com/eventname/example-event`. Now the URL of the CSS file is resolved to `https://example.com/eventname/styles.css` which is **not the correct path**.

The path, however, is still handled by the web server because it matches the URL wildcard you use for the event pages – `/eventname/:event`. That causes your application to render the `event.hbs` template which is obviously served with the MIME type `text/html` and not `text/css` as expected, hence the error *MIME type not supported*.

---

To fix this problem, you can:

- use an absolute (relative to your application's domain) path (`/styles.css` – note the `/`)
- use a valid relative path for every page (`../styles.css` in case of `/eventname/:event`)

Although both options work, I highly recommend the first one as it is easier to maintain.

Comment: Yes, I thought that too, but i have given relative path in every page and also made a static public directory. IDK why this is happening. However, will wait for few days and if none good answer shows up. I will accept yours.

Comment: Mmh, that's odd. Could you check what the stylesheet URL is returning? Just visit it in your browser. Also, could you include the line where you set up the static file serving and your `<link>` tag in your question? I'd love to help you actually fix this.

Comment: I opened [a pull request](https://github.com/alpitanand/Business/pull/1) to fix the issue.

Comment: let me check the request

Answer (score -1):

If you get that error that mean your folder is not in the public directory. Move it to the public directory and change the route of your files to (/style.css)